# MAKE drop down ready only if value is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am new in programming

i have 6 drop down in one page 1 want them to make them read only (non editable) 
if value is selected
and rest of the drop down should not be read only if value is selected

is there any way i can check all the Drop down in one condition/check(at one go)

thanks in advance

Comment: There are many ways of doing such? do you want it in `server side` or `Client side`?

Answer (score 0):

1# Find all dropdownlists

```
Dim allDDs = From dd As DropDownList In Me.Controls() Where TypeOf (dd) Is 
        DropDownList Select dd
```

2# disbale the where value selected and enable others

```
                    For Each d In allDDs
                        d.Enabled = d.SelectedValue = ""
                    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
say ddl1, ddl2, ddl3, ddl4, ddl5, ddl6 are ids of 6 dropdowns in your page.

        for (int count = 1; count <= 6; count++)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.ID = "ddl" + count;

            if (ddl.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                ddl.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ddl.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: but how will u know which DDL has value is selected !!

Comment: you asked for ddl1(first droopdown to be selected then first will become readonly and rest others will be deitable) ?? am i right?

Comment: if any of them(Drop downs) has value selected then it should be disabled otherwise enable so that user can edit it !!

Comment: okay , i m editing the answer as per your requirement, please wait!

Comment: @DeepakJain please check my edited answer, i have reduced if else statement for you, try this, this should work too.